# PHP POST Content-Length

Tags: php, file-upload

When i uploading file by simple form i've got

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 372220927 bytes exceeds the limit of 33554432 bytes in Unknown on line 0 
Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_upload\upload_file.php on line 3
```

I change in php_ini to 20M, my problem is that i want to echo nice msg error about too big file, no such warning. An error/execption i can try/catch.
Where i can found out about "warning" before call:

> $_FILES["file"]["error"]>0

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label></br>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"></br>
<input type="text" name="desc" id="desc"></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

//

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"]>0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> 33554432 bytes = ~32MB
>
> 372220927 bytes = ~355MB

You need to set [post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) and [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) to at least 355MB absolute minimum to allow the file to upload.

Follow this [example](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-353) on how to setup a PHP file upload form where you set the MAX_FILE_SIZE so that you can error back to user if that limit is exceeded. Check `$_FILES['userfile']['error']` to see if it is equal to the constant `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE` indicating that the file was larger than allowed. **Please note in example the warning about what order to place the INPUT fields**